# solve $y^\prime=\frac {y^2}{x^2} -\frac {y}{x}$ can't find my mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve 
$ y'=\frac{y^2}{x^2} - \frac{y}{x} $
but something went wrong but I can't find my mistake

$$y^\prime=y^2/x^2\ -y/x \\
y^\prime+y/x=y^2/x^2\\ 
y=v/x \\
(v/x)^\prime+(v/x\ \ )/x=(v/x)^2/x^2\\ 
v^\prime/x-v/x^2\ +v/x^2 =v^2/x^3\\ 
v^\prime/v^2 =1/x^2\\ 
-1/v=-1/x+c\\
v=1/(x+c)\\
yx=1/(x+c)\\ 
y=1/(x^2+cx)
$$

can you find it?

edit:
I tried @lostInspace correction and now I get this:

$
-1/v=-1/2x^2 +c
v=2x^2+c
yx=2x^2+c 
y=2x+c/x
$
which is not the answer.

Comment: What are all the backslashes for in your formatting of the post?  If you want a line-break, you can use two run-on back-slashes, like \\  or twice \\ \\, for a space between lines.

Comment: trying to... making it worse!

Comment: $y=vx $ is a better choice of substitution

Comment: Also $(v/x)^2/x^2 = v^2/x^4$, not $x^3$.

Comment: shouldn't it be e^(***-***integral(p))? @LostInSpace

Comment: If I were you I would substitute $y=vx$ to avoid mistakes

Comment: Peru, you should get simply $v'/v^2=1/x^3$ integrate.

Comment: @LostInSpace isn't it v'/v^2=1/x^3?

Comment: Yes then it gives $1/v=c+1/(2x^2)$

Comment: @LostInSpace but the answer seems to be different say, from wolfram's https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dy%5E2%2Fx%5E2-y%2Fx

Comment: Peru I got the same answer as WA  $y=\dfrac {2x}{2cx^2+1}$ And $2c=k$ gives WA's answer. Note that $v=y x$

Comment: @LostInSpace  ohh I got what the mistake was. I ignored the correlation between c v and x. thanks.

Comment: You're welcomed Peru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^\prime=y^2/x^2\ -y/x \\
y^\prime+y/x=y^2/x^2\\ 
y=v/x \\
(v/x)^\prime+(v/x\ \ )/x=(v/x)^2/x^2\\ 
v^\prime/x-v/x^2\ +v/x^2 =v^2/x^3\\ 
$$
You should have 
$$ \dfrac {v'x-v}{x^2} +v/x^2 =v^2/x^4 $$
A better choice of substitution is
$$y=vx \implies y'=v'x+v$$
The equation becomes:
$$v'x=v^2-2v$$

Comment: Nice!  Thanks ...

Comment: @amWhy Youi are completely right. I was editing when you commented Amwhy

Comment: tried to keep on from the mistake you've found, but I've gotten an incorrect solution @LostInSpace

Comment: You should post your new attempt so members can correct it @peru

Comment: @LostInSpace where should I?

Comment: Edit your original post @peru Just add an edit and your new attempt

Comment: I added. @LostInSpace

Answer (score 0):

As already said, start with $y= z x$ to make
$$x z'-z^2+2 z=0$$ which is separable.

You could even do now $z=\frac 1u$
$$x u'-2 u+1=0$$ which is still simpler